# Custom Navigation Transitions on iOS 7, how to manage the keyboard?

Tags: uiview, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, transition, uikeyboard

TabBarController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    PlaylistViewController *playlistViewController = [[PlaylistViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *otherViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *playlistNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:playlistViewController];
    playlistNavigationController.delegate = self;

    self.viewControllers = @[playlistNavigationController, otherViewController];

    playlistNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemDownloads tag:kTabBarTagPlaylist];
    playlistNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = @"Playlist";
    otherViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemMore tag:kTabBarTagOther];

    playlistNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC {

    if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush) return [[FadeTransition alloc] init];
    else if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop) return [[SlideTransition alloc] init];
    return nil;
}
```

PlaylistViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *storeBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Store"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                      target:self
                                                                      action:@selector(test)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = storeBarButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *currentlyPlayingButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Now playing"
                                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                              target:self
                                                                              action:@selector(test)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = currentlyPlayingButtonItem;

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Playlist";

    self.playlistTableViewController = [[PlaylistTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
    searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.playlistTableViewController.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

    [self addChildViewController:self.playlistTableViewController];

    [self.view addSubview:self.playlistTableViewController.view];
    self.playlistTableViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.playlistTableViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.playlistTableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

FadeTransition.m

```
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 0.5;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{

    /* view controllers */
    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    /* views */
    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    [containerView addSubview:fromVC.view];
    [containerView addSubview:toVC.view];

    /* settings */
    toVC.view.alpha = 0.0f; /* not visible at start */
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{

                         toVC.view.alpha = 1.0f; /* 100% visible at the end */
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [fromVC.view removeFromSuperview];
                         [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                     }];
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: Playlist's table]

[image: Search field]

[image]

When I touch one of the results, a new UIView gets pushed and animated by FadeTransition.

The keyboard automatically gets slided down, but I need to leave the keyboard opened (it should stay behind), how can I do it?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem, but I'd like to know the answer.